# Calculating the distance CGPoint travelled from one place to another

Tags: macos, swift2, mouseevent, cgpoint

What method do I have to use for calculating the distance that CGPoint travelled from its old position to new position?

```
var point: CGPoint = CGPointMake(x:50.0, y:50.0)
```

...and there is a method for dragging a point with LMB:

```
func mouseDragged(event: NSEvent) {

    var pointDragged = self.convertPoint(event.locationInWindow, fromView: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do you need to find X offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) and `mouseLocation = event.mouseLocation()` where `event` in your case is of type `NSEvent`.

```
let point1: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 2.0, y: 9.0)
let point2: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 4.0, y: 13.0)

let xDist = (point1.x - point2.x)
let yDist = (point1.y - point2.y)
let distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist))

print(distance)
```

`point1` would be your starting position and you can obtain the position where the user clicked - `point2`, from the `NSEvent` in your `mouseDragged` function:

```
mouseLocation = event.mouseLocation()
point2 = CGPointMake(mouseLocation.x, mouseLocation.y)
```